# Support both Standard mode and Quirks mode? Is that possible and necessary?

Tags: asp.net, html

Today I was assigned a bug saying that some page elements don't work on IE8 Quirks mode at all, and I need to fix them. The point is that I believe our pages will always be rendered in Standard mode, because we specify DOCTYPE at the beginning of every page (via master page). I'd think it must be some debugging tools changed that during testing.

I managed to convice QA to close it as by design, after a brief explanation to her. Now I start to think the question that whether we should have our page work on both Standard and Quirks mode. Maybe we should try to minimize the problem even if the page is not rendering in a supposed mode?

Any standard or best practices on that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use standards mode, as that will provide the most consistent experience across browsers and (especially) across browser versions. It's reasonable to expect that someday in the distant future, quirks mode will cease to be necessary, and standards mode will be all there is. It's already difficult enough making pages work in different browsers, and if you had to do it in different modes in different browsers (IE isn't the only browser with quirks mode), your work will get a whole lot harder.

Comment: @Mark I don't get it. Why is quirks mode necessary today?

Comment: @Šime It's necessary because there are millions of web pages out there right now that were written to work in old (and buggy) versions of web browsers, particularly Netscape 4, and Internet Explorer 4, 5, and 6. To get these pages to work correctly in new (more standards-compliant) browsers, the new browsers need to "emulate" the bugs in the early browsers. This is called quirks mode.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: not for a modern web apps. But trust me, there are plenty of web-sites that are entirely run in the Quirks mode.

Comment: Yup. All the pages I have now in the projects target Standard mode. I'm just wondering that whether I need to think about how they're gonna being rendered in Quirks mode, even I know they're not supposed to be?

Comment: The previous website I worked on: msnbc.com, is still working on Quirks mode at all.

Comment: @Mark But the OP asked from a web developer's perspective, not a browser maker's one. If one develops web-pages with the correct DOCTYPE (a doctype that triggers standards mode), then one does not have to deal with quirks mode, right?

Comment: @Šime Yes, that's correct. And that's the way all development should be happening right now.

Comment: @tshao I feel for you. Browser incompatibilities are painful enough without having to deal with quirks mode...

Answer (score 1):

All the modern web-browsers will respect the DOCTYPE definition and won't fall into the Quirks mode.

Although I saw some cases when IE rendered a page in a Quirks mode even though there was a valid DOCTYPE defined in the markup. The cause of the problem was the fact that the page was placed into the frame and the "parent" page didn't have a valid DOCTYPE definition.

So my advice would be: always declare a valid DOCTYPE for your pages. In this case you don't need to worry about all those tricky cases with debugging tools enabled, etc.

-- Pavel

Comment: Thanks Pavel. I agree with you and that's what I did. I just want to know whether I (or our lovely QA :) should think about how these pages will look like under Quirks mode (maybe for debugging purpose)?

Comment: Well, we always use the DOCTYPE and our QA engineers don't expect our applications to work in Quricks mode ;-)